# Chrome bookmarks problem with Roaming profile

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, roaming-profile

i have a strange problem :/

Here's the context :

Roughly 30 PC clients on a domain (win 2012r2)
Roaming profil activated via GPO
Google Chrome for everybody

Some of my users have a problem with their Bookmarks on Chrome, in fact, they multiply itselves with each reboot/launch.

At first, i quickly fixed this by deleting /AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/ in the user's session and everything was ok but now it's not working anymore for at least 1 user and i need to figure out what's the problem before it spread wider.

Chrome was updated to very last version, no change

Anyone has an idea please ?

Comment: this may be a better fit for https://superuser.com

Comment: @mb21 Thanks, posted :)